# Typecasting the Reference of a Double Variable

Tags: c, casting

I have a question about typecasting the reference of a variable of type double. What is exactly happening when `&d` becomes typecasted into an `unsigned char*`? How is typecasting the address of a variable valid and what is it actually doing?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void) {
    // examining object representation is a legitimate use of cast
    double d = 3.14;
    printf("The double %.2f(%a) is: ", d, d);
    for(size_t n = 0; n < sizeof d; ++n)
        printf("0x%02x ", ((unsigned char*)&d)[n]); // <--
}
```

And how do the array brackets work in this case?

Comment: in this use case the typecast doesn't matter because all pointers are likely the same size on your platform (4 bytes on 32 bit, 8 bytes on some 64 bit architectures) -- it will only matter when you attempt to dereference that address to either read or write the value there -- once you do that non-pointer part of the type information will specify a size to read or write from the address -- in the case of unsigned char, 1 byte e.g. ((unsigned char *) p) = 0xff;

Comment: So I'm basically turning the hex into a printable item I'm guessing. If that's the case then why the `*` in the typecast?

Comment: the * makes it a pointer type when used in the context of a typecast, when used outside it it is the dereference operator -- the best way to understand what is really happening is to compile your program with gcc -S, remove the printf call and just cast something and assign it to a variable of that type, you'll probably see a movb instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&d` represents a pointer to the location at which the value of the double is stored.
A pointer is simply a memory address (likely a 64-bit value) which identifies a location in memory, regardless of the type of data that is being pointed to.

This makes the cast from a `double *` to an `unsigned char *` possible as the representation of both is simply a word of memory. The array notation then dereferences this pointer and adds n times the size of a char (1 byte), and then reads the next char-many bits.

The array notation `a[n]` is equivalent to `*(a+n)`. It is simply adding an offset to the pointer referred to by `a`.

Comment: Wait how can an address of a variable also be a pointer?

Comment: A pointer in C is a variable containing an integer value pointing to a memory address in C.

You can see that a pointer is just an integer by executing something like `printf("%p\n", some_pointer);`, which will output the hexcode representation of the pointer.

If this is a new concept, you may want to look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

Comment: But `d` wasn't declared as a pointer so how can `&d` be a pointer?

Comment: The operator `&` applied to `d` returns the value of the memory address containing `d`. That is to say, you are returned a new integer value identifying the location in memory at which `d` is stored, which is therefore a pointer to `d`.

Comment: this is honestly bamboozling me since I have always seen the ampersand operator as something that returns the address and not really referred to as a pointer in this case.

Comment: A pointer is just an integer value containing the address of some variable.

In this case the two words are pretty much synonymous.

The value returned by the `&` may be de-referenced using a `*`, just like any other pointer.

Comment: So then what about the brackets? Since it's not an array is it interacting with the bits instead and not a continuous line of values or something along those lines?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226582/discussion-between-maxcampman-and-the-programming-m16a4).